# Issue with using both @JsonIgnore and @JsonProperty in jackson mixins

Tags: java, json, annotations, jackson

I have a use case for using both `@JsonIgnore` and `@JsonProperty` in a jackson mixin.

Here is my mixin:

```
public abstract class MessageMixin {
    @JsonIgnore
    Member sender;

    @JsonIgnore
    Member recipient;

    @JsonProperty("senderId")
    Long getSenderId() {
        return sender.getId();
    }

    @JsonProperty("recipientId")
    Long getRecipientId() {
        return recipient.getId();
    }

    @JsonProperty("senderFirstName")
    String getSenderFirstName() {
        return sender.getFirstName();
    }

    @JsonProperty("recipientFirstName")
    String getRecipientFirstName() {
        return recipient.getFirstName();
    }
}
```

The `sender` and `recipient` fields are correctly ignored but none of the `@JsonProperty` fields are added.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Do you have a base `Message` class, or is there only `Member` and you are trying to create the concept of "Message" with your Mix-in? I think there is a chance you are using a Mix-in when a VO would be more appropriate. Are you registering your Mix-in on the `ObjectMapper` like this: `addMixIn(Message.class, MessageMixin.class)`? If so, what does `Message` look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mix-ins are useful for applying Jackson configuration to classes without modifying the source code of the target class. Mix-ins can be thought of as a configuration layer that sits above a class that Jackson will look at for instructions during de/serialization. A benefit of Mix-ins is that they decouple Jackson-specific  config from your project code, allowing you to rip out Jackson and use a new framework without having to modify all of your VOs. That being said it would be odd to extend a Mix-in for purposes of instantiation. I think you'll want to avoid logic like `sender.getFirstName()` in your Mix-in, and allow the base class to populate values. For example, for a Mix-in you have provided I would expect a base class with public `sender` and `recipient` members, and your Mix-in to be entirely abstract.

### If `Message` is a class that already exists

Assuming a base class like this:

```
public class Message {
    public Member sender;
    public Member recipient;

    public Message(Member sender, Member recipient) {
        this.sender = sender;
        this.recipient = recipient;
    }

    public Long getSenderId() {
        return sender.getId();
    }

    public Long getRecipientId() {
        return recipient.getId();
    }

    public String getSenderFirstName() {
        return sender.getFirstName();
    }

    public String getRecipientFirstName() {
        return recipient.getFirstName();
    }
}
```

Without a Mix-in, this class would produce:

```
{
    "sender": {
        "id": 883,
        "firstName": "Bob"
    },
    "recipient": {
        "id": 3993,
        "firstName": "Jilly"
    },
    "senderId": 883, 
    "recipientId": 3993, 
    "senderFirstName": "Bob", 
    "recipientFirstName": "Jilly"
}
```

To introduce a Mix-in and ignore `sender` and `recipient` without modifying `Message`, the Mix-in must be registered with the `ObjectMapper`.

The Mix-in could look like this:

```
public abstract class MessageMixin {
    @JsonIgnore
    Member sender;

    @JsonIgnore
    Member recipient;

    @JsonProperty("senderId")
    abstract Long getSenderId();

    @JsonProperty("recipientId")
    abstract Long getRecipientId();

    @JsonProperty("senderFirstName")
    abstract String getSenderFirstName();

    @JsonProperty("recipientFirstName")
    abstract String getRecipientFirstName();
}
```

The `ObjectMapper` config like this:

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper()
        .addMixIn(Message.class, MessageMixin.class);
```

And it would output the following JSON:

```
{
    "senderId": 883,
    "senderFirstName": "Bob",
    "recipientFirstName": "Jilly",
    "recipientId": 3993
}
```

### If `Message` does not exist

If no `Message` base class exists then you are probably better off creating a simple POJO to accomplish the "Message" representation. Something like this will play nicely with serialization and deserialization.

```
public class MessagePojo {
    private final Member sender;
    private final Member recipient;

    @JsonCreator
    public MessagePojo(@JsonProperty("sender") Member sender,
                       @JsonProperty("recipient") Member recipient) {
        this.sender = sender;
        this.recipient = recipient;
    }

    @JsonProperty("senderId")
    public Long getSenderId() {
        return sender.getId();
    }

    @JsonProperty("recipientId")
    public Long getRecipientId() {
        return recipient.getId();
    }

    @JsonProperty("senderFirstName")
    public String getSenderFirstName() {
        return sender.getFirstName();
    }

    @JsonProperty("recipientFirstName")
    public String getRecipientFirstName() {
        return recipient.getFirstName();
    }
}
```